# Rectangular matrix interpolation with python

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I need to interpolate rectangular matrix and I try to do it with interp2d attribute of scipy, but I have error says me I can interpolate only square matrix:

```
ValueError: x and y must have equal lengths for non rectangular grid
```

So, how to interpolate rectangular matrix? Code I use (gives error):

```
min, max = 0, 14
X = np.linspace(min, max, 720)
Y = np.linspace(min, max, 360)
x, y = np.meshgrid(X, Y, sparse=True)

f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, matrix, kind='cubic')

X_new = np.linspace(min, max, 1440)
Y_new = np.linspace(min, max, 720)

final = f(X_new, Y_new)
```

Comment: For your `final` matrix, you also need to put `X_new` and `Y_new` into a `meshgrid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about your `matrix` is, but I think you need to check first the shape of `matrix`. If the length of `X` and `Y` have the same length with the shape of `matrix`, you can successfully run the code. To check the shape, you can use `print(matrix.shape)` (make sure you have `matrix` in ndarray numpy).

This code has been working for me.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

min, max = 0, 14
X = np.linspace(min, max, 720)
Y = np.linspace(min, max, 360)
x, y = np.meshgrid(X, Y, sparse=True)
matrix = np.abs(x**2+y**2)

f = interpolate.interp2d(X, Y, matrix, kind='cubic')

X_new = np.linspace(min, max, 1440)
Y_new = np.linspace(min, max, 720)

final = f(X_new, Y_new)
```